# Basics need to study quantum field theory after graduation?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, education

What are the fundamental basics that i need to study quantum field theory? basics of Mathematics and physics??

Comment: Can any one give a step by step  Way to reach field theory

Comment: I am uncomfortable with the mathematical notations of field theory...... I realize that its due to the lack of my knowledge...... Can any one motivate me?

Comment: It would be best if you first start with classical mechanics, quantum mechanics and then electro dynamics. Also, it is important to know the 4-formalism in QM, so you should maybe also prepare on relativistic quantum mechanics. In mathematics I would say you need to be familiar with functionals and functional derivatives and also 4-derivatives and integrals.